# Troubleshooting STK Message Generation in Web App - No Messages Generated

Tags: reactjs

Failing to return an STK message after an order has been made.

I am creating a restaurant website whereby once a person has booked any type of food to be delivered the system will send an STK message with the food ordered, the time that will be taken for the food to be delivered and the price to be paid after delivery. I am using React. please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.